# Issue with Swift: value of optional type '[Int : Int]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm currently learning swift and I'm trying to create a function which will update a story based on which button is pressed. I already have the button press bit set up but then I pass the tag of the button pressed to the `updateStory` function.

```
func updateStory(myTag: Int) {

    let next = [
        1 : [
            1 : 3,
            2 : 2,
        ],
        2 : [
            1 : 3,
            2 : 4,
        ],
        3 : [
            1 : 6,
            2 : 5,
        ]
    ]

    // Error:(86, 17) value of optional type '[Int : Int]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
    if (next[storyIndex][myTag] != nil) {
        let nextStory = next[storyIndex][myTag]
        storyIndex = nextStory
    }

}
```

StoryIndex is defined as a global variable within the class.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do what compiler is suggesting you to do. There will be `red circle` on the right side, click that then there will be `fix` also so just click that and issue will be fixed.

Comment: Since you're the developer you should be aware of what you do , you should know when to select **!** and when to select **?** , it's not a bad idea using **!**  ,  the SO stupid developers always consider **!** because it will crash , but it will occur only with a none-IOS developer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because dictionary look ups return an optional (the key might be missing), you need to unwrap the result of `next[storyIndex]` before you can index it.  Use `?` (*optional chaining*) here to safely unwrap the value.  Since you need the result, instead of comparing to `nil`, use `if let` (*optional binding*):

```
if let nextStory = next[storyIndex]?[myTag] {
    storyIndex = nextStory
}
```

If `storyIndex` is not a valid key, then `next[storyIndex]` will be `nil`, and the result of the optional chain will be `nil`.  If `myTag` is not a valid key, the result will also be `nil`.  In the case that both keys are valid, the result of the optional chain will be `Int?` and `nextStory` will be bound to the unwrapped value.

---

If you have a default value to use for `storyIndex` (such as `1`) if the look ups fail, you can use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` also with the *optional chain* to do this in one line:

```
storyIndex = next[storyIndex]?[myTag] ?? 1
```

or (to leave `storyIndex` unchanged for lookup failure):

```
storyIndex = next[storyIndex]?[myTag] ?? storyIndex
```